# Doubt concerning the definition of $p$ and $-p$ in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, momentum, conventions, notation

We can define the field in term of the ladder operators as:
$$
\phi(\vec{x}) \propto \int d^3p \left( a_{\vec{p}}e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} + a^\dagger_{\vec{p}}e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} \right)
$$
similarly, to the conjugated momentum:
$$
\pi(\vec{x}) \propto \int  d^3p \left(  a_{\vec{p}}e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} - a^\dagger_{\vec{p}}e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} \right).
$$

However, in Peskin and Schroeder's book, they state that we can rearrange these two equations as
$$
\phi(\vec{x}) \propto \int d^3p \left( a_{\vec{p}} + a^\dagger_{-\vec{p}} \right) e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}
$$
and
$$
\pi(\vec{x}) \propto \int d^3p \left( a_{\vec{p}} - a^\dagger_{-\vec{p}} \right) e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}
$$
what exactly are we doing? Are we changing the interpreting of the operators, creating/destroying particles with negative $p$? Is this to just simplify the notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that since the integrals are taken over the entire real line, i.e.:

$$\int_\infty^\infty\int_\infty^\infty\int_\infty^\infty dp_xdp_ydp_z:=\int d^3p \tag{1}$$

there is no harm in changing $p_i\mapsto -p_i$ (as long as we add the change of sign *everywhere the $p_i$ is found in that term*), in particular we have to change it in the exponential of the second term, which then allows us to factor it out, giving your final expressions.

Comment: I find it surprising that, after a correct answer has already been given,  someone else writes down the same answer, albeit with more details. Not only that but the later answer gets more upvotes?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, perhaps others think your answer is overly concise and doesn't properly explain how to arrive at the last formula in OP's question? Your answer is 8 words. And for what it's worth it's possible for more than one correct answer to be given to the same question and at that point it's up to the community to decide which answer should be highest rated. This is kind of a bizarre thing to be upset about on what is likely to be a rather low profile question. @Oбжорoв

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I ma not upset at all, but I see this happening more and more. It seems that many users seem more interested in increasing their reputation than helping people by answering questions.

Comment: I am sorry, but It is not like your answer was wrong, I understood it through it, but this one is more complete.

Comment: @Oбжорoв You specifically came onto my answer to complain about the fact that it "gets more upvotes", then one comment later you accuse others of being "more interested in increasing their reputation than helping people"? I don't follow and this is starting to rub me the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a change of integration variables.